# Getting protocol http/https part of the landing page

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am getting landingpage and hostname to get the full url of the landing page of my website.But it doesn't list https or http part of protocol.
Kindly let me know how can i get the protocol part of the url

Comment: it's very odd that we have such a low number of replies to the forum where we are advised to post our questions  rather then Google own group.s
Google have to dedicate some resources for stack-overflow [there advised area to post Google analytic api questions] or at least advice some of there staff to at least visit these question posted here.

Comment: Why do you think SO is "Google advised area for analytics api questions"? This is not what it says in the docs I found: https://developers.google.com/analytics/community/

Comment: I were posting at some google group on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum and there were a post recommending to query on stack overflow for google analytics problem. i will try to find out it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protocol is not sent to Google Analytics by default. If that's important to you it's better to track that using a custom variable or custom dimension.

eg:

```
(...)
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXX-X']);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'protocol', document.location.protocol, 3]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
(...)
```

Comment: By the was Eduardo isn't it tedious to provide this thing via custom variable.I think they should have the protocol info somewhere in there db. I am providing some custom variable to them but that is purely a thing which they don't know.It looks odd that they have knowledge of landing page but no knowledge of the protocol from which request is submitted.